# equivalent cURL --data-binary @filename -H "Content-Type:text/csv" in java

Tags: java, http, curl

I am using Apache http client, using cURL, the command would be:

```
curl -i -X POST --data-binary @data.csv -H "Content-Type:text/csv" "http://localhost:8080/"
```

What is the equivalent in Java(Apache Http Client) ? I tried the following:

```
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("...");
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
File file = new File("data.csv");
builder.addBinaryBody("upfile", file, ContentType.create("text/csv"), "data.csv");
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
postRequest.setEntity(entity);
client.execute(postRequest);
```

Comment: When you run the Java code, what is the problem? Any error or unexpected result?

Comment: @shaochuancs I got no errors, just looks like the request did not really perform(I expected to insert some data into the database after the request).

Comment: Have you check the server log? Is the request received?

Comment: The request is received, just seems the csv header is not parsed correctly, it is "empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,sal,comm,deptno" and in java it is changed to "--otalfEoCmr8miD1h4SiWwqG6f2iI93Rrf"

Answer (score 1):

That `curl` sends the file contents as the body (entity) directly, not in a multipart. Try

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File(filename),ContentType.create("text/csv")));
    ... client.execute(post) ...
```

PS: `curl -d/--data[-*]` already uses POST, you don't need `-X`.